# Showing live results from my PHP import process to the user

Tags: php, jquery, phalcon

I am wanting to create an import function for the import of orders into my web system. The upload will be processed through posting the input file through JQuery and an Ajax call. I would like to have a box where live results of the import is displayed to the user.

For example, if an order file has 10 orders in it, I would like to update the user interface after each order has been imported so that the user can see it's progress.

Is this possible at all through PHP and JQuery?

Comment: One way is to update a session variable at every import with import details and then through ajax, showing the updated session value in client side.

Comment: That could work.. and then use a loop with a timeout in Jquery to continually poll a page that outputs that session variable...

Comment: Depends on your server / installation. In IIS (PHP via FastCGI) on my dev machine new requests from the same session as the initial one are queued until the first request is completed. So every user has only one active request at a time.

Comment: @MarkusMüller- I'm not entirely sure what you mean...

Comment: Yup, I had implemented this before to check current state of data being inserted, if you know total number of imports, then a dynamic loader can also be placed, similar to gmail.